# Don't know why Memory is increasing, Leakage Tool

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, instruments

I don't have any experience with errors like this. When I start an action with one button, the memory is increasing over time. With the leak tool I got this result.

[image]

In my Content View I have a class GameScene which is a SKScene and a class which handles some calculations (observable object) like so:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var calculations: Calc //<- is a class
    
    var scene: GameScene //<- is a class


    init(){
       let hereCalc = Calc()

       scene = GameScene(calc: hereCalc)
       calculations = hereCalc
    }

    var body: some View{
         MyButton(game: scene, calc: calculations)
    }


}
```

When I am tapping the button, I modify some properties of the classes and call functions.
One function is the game.start() which causes that isPaused is setted to false so that the update function is called. In the game function I am calling a step function from calc where the properties are updated.
The game class has a property calc.

```
class GameScene: SKScene,ObservableObject{

    var myCalc: Calc
    
    init(calc: Calc){
        myCalc = calc
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        myCalc.step()
    }

}
```

I don't know why the memory is increasing, but I hope that the info in my description would help to seeing the problem, I don't know what it could be. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: are you using debug mode?

Comment: Look at the stack trace and see if you recognise any names from your code, if you don't, your job just got a heck of a lot harder

Comment: It could be that each time you update something inside mycalc grows? Try to think about where there are data structures that might expand.

Comment: 64 bytes per button press, I wouldn't worry about that. Memory issues are literally a million times bigger than that.

Comment: The problem is that if I press the button the scenes ispaused property is set to false. Then in the update function is the step() function of the Calc class called. This causes that the properties of calc getting updated so that some shapes in views get redrawn. Perhaps I could try to commend the step function out and then I could say if it is something else.

Comment: I don't know why, but if I have a @ObservedObject gameScene and in this class a property with the calculations class (@Published) there is no/or not as fast growing memory